# What is the simplest way to calculate distance in a 3D environment?

Tags: 3d, mathematics

What is the simplest way to programmatically calculate difference between two points in a 3D game environment?

I am trying to sort a list of light sources by how close they are to an entity, so that only the four closest light sources affect an entity at any given time.

Comment: Most vector libraries should have a built in function to compute the (squared) length of a vector.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compute the vector representing the displacement between the two points `p0` and `p1`:

```
v = p1 - p0
```

and then compute the length of that vector:

```
distance = sqrt(dot(v, v))
```

---

A vector in this case is an element of the real 3D coordinate space, so it has three components (X, Y and Z). A point also has the same three coordinates, and we can subtract two points from eachother to get the vector representing the *displacement* between those points. Both vector and point subtraction is done component-wise, which means you do the operation on each component separately. For the first line above (`v = p1 - p0`), you're basically doing

```
v.x = p1.x - p0.x
v.y = p1.y - p0.y
v.z = p1.z - p0.z
```

where (`v.x` et cetera are the individual scalar components of the vector, and so on).

In the second equation we're taking the [vector dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of `v` with itself. The dot product has lots of useful applications but in this case I'm just using it for brevity. The dot product of a 3D vector has a *scalar* result (a single number), and that number is calculated for two vectors `a` and `b` as

```
(a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y) + (a.z * b.z)
```

which in our specific case translates to

```
(v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z)
```

This is the same as ["`v.x` squared plus `v.y` squared..."](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vch04/vch04_8.html) When you take the square root of that resulting scalar, you get what is known as the *magnitude* or *length* of the vector. The length of the vector is the distance you travel when, starting from some origin (`p0` in this case) you displace yourself *by* the vector arriving at some destination (`p1`).

It is thus the quantity you want to sort your entities by. Note however that if you *only* need to compare distances, and not otherwise use the actual accurate value of the distance, you can omit the slightly-costly square root from the computation since it will not change the relative ordering of the values.

Comment: I'm not the best with vector math, could you elaborate on the mechanics behind this? What does each step actually do?

Comment: If you're doing anything in a 3D environment, you'll want to be familiar with this stuff. It's pretty basic and you can find good reference material online or good books about it relatively easy. I strongly recommend you do so. I'll edit my answer to break the above operations down into their component parts, though.

Comment: At one point I was good with vector math, but that day has long since passed. Calculus seems to have washed it all from my head. Guess I've got some reading to do.

Comment: In surprised that noone had mentioned that this formula is just applying a [translation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) and the 3D variant of the Pythagoras Theorem. The relation `distance^2 = dot(vec, vec)` is just Pythagoras Theorem written in terms of vectors `distance^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2` for three dimensional vector, recalling that dot-product is just notation for element-wise multiplication. Skipping the square rooting is an insight that you'd have if you notice that squaring or rooting a list of positive numbers never change their relative orders.

Comment: The sqrt function has poor performance. You should use faster  approximations

Answer (score 2):

`abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)`, [as proposed by this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/92523/1430) will not always be correct.  If you are willing to perform two more multiplication, you can perform an exact ordering without the cost of a squareroot.

Consider the distances from `(0,0)` to the points `(3, 4)` and `(5, 1)`.   The distances are `5` and `~5.09`, but the abs algorithm shows `(5, 1)` as being closer.

If you want to compare absolute differences without performing the square root, compute the square of the euclidian distance like this:

`(x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)`

Comment: Note that this site isn't a forum, and posting answers "responding" to other posts doesn't work well (you should use comments for that usually), since posts aren't always displayed in an order that would make such a thing readable. I linked the answer you were responding to to try to alleviate future confusion with your response.

Answer (score 1):

abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2) + abs(z1 - z2) is much more efficient than using square root. If you don't need the actual distance, and just need to compare distances, this is the way to go.

There will be a margin of error here, so it will give you a rough sort. Thanks to David for pointing this out

Comment: Is this always correct? Or is there a margin of error?

Comment: Right, thats what I meant. So sorting will always be in the right order, but the actual value is wrong. Sounds like just what I need.

Comment: A good example would be when you have to sort many objects by distance. Actual distance may not be as important but the relative order is.

Comment: Distance from origin to point A (2,2) vs point B (3,0). Actual distance to A is 2.83, and to B is 3.0. A is closer. By "taxicab distance" we'd say that A is further, which is wrong. Sorry! Taxicab distance has its uses, but _accurate_ sorting isn't one of them.

Comment: What you _can_ do is remove the square root from the chozen answer above, and say M = dot(diff,diff) = (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2, instead of sqrt(M), which is sufficient for sorting.

Comment: That's a good point that I neglected to bring up in my answer, so I added it.

Comment: No, this answer can give erroneous results.

Comment: @Octopus as stated in the answer

Comment: @Evorlor, its bad enough that it should be completely avoided, imo. Just sum the squares, you still avoid the sqrt and you have a list of d_squareds that can be sorted with 100% confidence.

Comment: This is not the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), it's [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Comment: I upvoted because sometimes manhattan distance is really what you want, especially if we're talking about path planning in a grid environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the distance formula:

Formula:

`sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)^2 + (p2.y - p1.y)^2 + (p2.z - p1.z)^2)`

Code:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2) + Math.pow(p2.z - p1.z, 2))
```